# Perform find & replace in excel doc in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, excel, openxml

I am trying to create a postage label that is populated dynamically in C#.

What I thought I could do was create the label in Excel so I could get the layout perfect, then use OpenXML to replace the fields.  i.e. I have fields called things like `XXAddressLine1XX`, where I want to edit the XML and replace that text with the actual `Address Line 1` from the database.

Has anyone actually done something similar to this before and could post some code up that I could try?  I've used OpenXML to do this with word documents before, but I can't seem to find the XML data for the Excel document when using OpenXML in c# so am struggling to make progress.

Either that, or are there any better methods I could try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every now and then, there's a programming problem that is best solved with a non-programming solution. Businesses have had the need for printing mailing labels *en masse* for a long time, and in recent decades programs like Microsoft Word make this really simple via the "mail merge" feature. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/demo-use-mail-merge-to-format-and-print-mailing-labels-HA001190394.aspx for an example.

Word's mail merge will allow you to connect to a variety of data sources. The given example uses an Excel spreadsheet, but you can also use Access or SQL Databases, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I don't actually need to create labels en masse - each customer would just print of the label they require, but I will have a look at the link anyway

Comment: Ah, I see. So this is a program that will create a file for customers to use to print their labels? Another option may be to use a PDF writer. That will probably give you better control over the output, and it won't require your customers to have Excel installed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice StriplingWarrior.  I noticed that the application already used PDFSharp so I abandoned the Excel/XML thing and just drew the label straight to PDF.  Job done - a much better result too!

Answer (score 1):

The purely academic answer is: it's possible. I wrote a set of template parsing classes that search through a PowerPoint presentation replacing tags from a mark-up language I invented with charts and dynamic text objects fetched from a database. The trickiest part of the string replacement bit was handling tags that occurred across `Run` elements inside a `Paragraph` element. This occurs usually if you use special characters such as '{' or spaces in your tags. I was able to solve it by storing the text of the entire `TextBody` element in a gigantic character array (in your case it would be the contents of a `Cell` element), storing a list of extents that enumerated where in the character array each `Run` element began and ended, and then walking the character array while paying attention to the `Run` boundaries appropriately. Mind that if your tag spans across multiple `Run` elements you'd need to remove any extras and snip content across boundaries before you inserted the replacement `Run`. Unfortunately I cannot post any code because the work was done for a company, but that's the general idea of how to achieve it. I was not able to handle any newline cases (i.e. a tag occurs with a newline in it) because that would require writing a cross `Paragraph` indexer, which was beyond the scope of what I wanted to achieve. That could be done as well, but it would be significantly more difficult I think.

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell script extension PSExcel have an search and replace feature:

[PSExcel:](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel

```
Import-Module d:\psexcel\trunk\PSExcel\PSExcel

# Get commands in the module
Get-Command -Module PSExcel

# Get help for a command
Get-Help Import-XLSX -Full

 # Modify the path of the Excel file to your local svn ceck-out
 Get-ChildItem "C:\tmp\Source" -Filter *.xlsx | Foreach-Object{
    $fileName = $_.FullName

    # Open an existing XLSX to search and set cells within
    $Excel = New-Excel -Path $_.FullName

    $Workbook = $Excel | Get-Workbook

    #$Excel | Get-Worksheet
    $Worksheet = $Workbook | Get-Worksheet -Name "Sheet1"


    #Search for any cells like 'Chris'.  Set them all to Chris2
    $Worksheet | Search-CellValue {$_ -like 'Chris'} -As Passthru | Set-CellValue -Value "Chris2"

    #Save your changes and close the ExcelPackage
    $Excel | Save-Excel -Close
 }
```