# Advanced Find And Replace In Excel

Tags: excel, replace

I have a product list excel sheet, and category list excel sheet.

In the category excel there is cat_id and cat_name one corresponds to the other.

I need to do a find and replace on every cat_id and replace the numbers in the product list with the cat_name.

How would I do this in excel?

Comment: You can create a new column in your Product List and use VLOOKUP() to find the corresponding cat_name from the Category sheet.

Comment: You have to use `.Find` See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972850/item-not-found-in-find-vba

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can achieve what you are looking for with just Excel formulas in one step. However, you could use the following approach.

Let's assume that the product list sheet is called `ProductList` and the other one is called `CategoryList`. Also, let's say that the `cat_id` items on sheet `ProductList` are in column `A` and the `cat_id` and `cat_name` columns on sheet `CategoryList` are in columns `A` and `B`.

First you have to make sure that the items on sheet `CategoryList` are sorted in ascending order on `cat_id`. Then, in a cell on the first line of an empty column on sheet `ProductList` (let's say that is cell `Q1`) , enter the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP($A1,CategoryList!A:A,CategoryList!B:B)
```

Then select cell `Q1` and drag the lower right corner all the way down until the end of the data in your sheet. After this, column `Q` will contain the desired values.

To actually replace the original values in column `A` with those in `Q`, you need to copy whole column `Q` and do "Paste Special" into column `A`, where you select the radiobutton "Values". After that, you can delete the temporary column `Q`.

If you want to be robust with regard to `cat_id` items not present on sheet `CategoryList`, you could add a check, which makes the formula as follows (on one line):

```
=IF($A1<>LOOKUP($A1,CategoryList!A:A,CategoryList!A:A),
    "Not Found",LOOKUP($A1,CategoryList!A:A,CategoryList!B:B))
```

Comment: i got it working its all on one sheet when i drag the black square though it changes all the numbers.. i had to define the cells length though to get it to work.. im using open office

=LOOKUP(A1,B1:B210,C1:C210)

and when i drag the square it turns into

=LOOKUP(A2,B2:B211,C2:C2110) and it presents a problem.. i just need the a1 to change not the other ones.

how can i drag the square and only have the a column increment?

Comment: If you want your row numbers to remain the same while dragging the black square, you should add a $ sign before the numbers that you want to remain constant, as in =LOOKUP(A1,B$1:B$210,C$1:C$210).

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell script extension PSExcel have some join feature:

[PSExcel:](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel

Method:
`Join-Worksheet -Path`

I have tried the search and replace with success.
Also refer to my answer here:
[Perform find & replace in excel doc in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792681/perform-find-replace-in-excel-doc-in-c-sharp/41974151#41974151)